# Cucumber tests passing when they should not pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, cucumber

I am fairly new to cucumber.  I'm trying to write a test to ensure that a user doesn't create a duplicate tag.  So wrote a feature that reads as follows:

```
Scenario: Analyst adds a duplicate privacy tag
  Given I have a privacy tag called "Green"
  When I try to create a tag called "Green"
  Then I should be on the new privacy tag page
  And I should see an error message for "Green"
```

My steps are defined thusly:

```
Given /^I have a privacy tag called "(.*?)"$/ do |tag|
    PrivacyTag.create(:content => tag)
end

When /^I try to create a tag called "(.*?)"$/ do |arg1|
    visit new_privacy_tag_path
    fill_in 'privacy_tag[content]', :with => arg1
    click_button 'Create'
end

Then /^I should be on the new privacy tag page$/ do
    new_privacy_tag_path
end

Then /^I should see an error message for "(.*?)"$/ do |arg1|
    page.should have_selector('div', :class => 'alert alert-error') do |flash|
        flash.should have_content fartknocker
    end
end
```

So the strange thing is that all of these tests are passing right now.  When you try to create a duplicate privacy tag the application allows it and you end up on the privacy tag index page, the user is not returned to the new_privacy_tag_path.  But the test still passes.  And Cucumber doesn't even blink an eye at the fact that there is no variable defined anywhere called fartknocker and that the word fartknocker doesn't appear on the page anywhere.  The test still passes.  What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `page.should have_selector` doesn't take a block.  What you're probably looking for is the `within` method:

```
page.within('div', :class => 'alert alert-error') do
    page.should have_content fartknocker
end
```

Edit:
Since in your code, the line `flash.should have_content fartknocker` is inside a block that won't ever get run, then Ruby never evaluates it so has no chance to complain about the missing variable.

Comment: I made that change and now cucumber recognizes that fartknocker isn't something valid.  But all the tests are still passing even though it should fail on the last two.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with using Cucumber with Rails, in particular what you get built-in with path assertions etc... but I think that your step 'I should be on the new privacy tag page' is lacking an actual assertion.  Try `page.current_path.should == new_privacy_tag_path`

Comment: I guess the example that I was working off of was flawed.  Your changes are producing the expected results.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Then /^I should be on the new privacy tag page$/ do
  new_privacy_tag_path
end
```

That doesn't assert anything. So it will always be green.

```
Then /^I should see an error message for "(.*?)"$/ do |arg1|
  page.should have_selector('div', :class => 'alert alert-error') do |flash|
    flash.should have_content fartknocker
  end
end
```

Also you have to be careful with `have_content` it `/matches/` vs `"equals"`. And what Jon M mentioned in his answer is something you will need to address.

Comment: So have_selector can take a block of code?  Jon M said that it could not.